Debounced s3 notifications to execute a lambda
I want to run a task once whenever a specific folder is modified in a bucket, no matter how many files are in the modification, it has to run once in that period of time.
The issue with the classic s3 trigger is that it sends a notification for each element (even if it was in the same upload), which results in the task running n times.
Just for fun tried the SNS but with the same result.
I've seen exemples with SQS but with concurrency purposes.

What is the nature of the updates. Does x number of objects change once a day or are many objects changing on random intervals during the day?

@RossBush Option B: n number of objects at any time.

S3 doesn't have folders, just object prefixes, and there is no concept of "debounce notifications by object prefix" in S3. You will have to build something yourself to handle this.
A few options I can think of:

You could have a Lambda function take in the original S3 event notification, and push that to an SQS FIFO queue with a deduplication ID of the S3 path prefix. Then have the thing that does the processing poll for messages in the SQS queue. This would only work if your debounce time period is 5 minutes though, because that's the only time period that SQS deduplication works for.

You could have a Lambda function that runs on every event notification, and checks to see if the S3 path prefix is already in a DynamoDB table. If it is already in there then the Lambda function just exits and does nothing. If it is not in there, then it inserts it into the DymamoDB table and proceeds with whatever processing logic you need to perform.
With this solution you would use something like DynamoDB conditional update/inserts to prevent any concurrency issues with the DB lookup/inserts. And you would use DynamoDB TTL to expire the records after your time period has elapsed.

You could also build something similar with a Lambda function and Redis ElastiCache or MemoryDB instead of DynamoDB.




For the first option: I like the dedup id, but not so much the polling, even thought it would be the simulation of the debouncing. What would be the "thing" that polls? a cron Cloudwatch event? but how to sync the sqs notif with the 5 mins cron?

The second option is more reactive, although it doesn't give any debounce time; dynamoDB could schedule a lambda on insert with a delay?

The second option gives a debounce time via the TTL on the record. Whatever TTL you set on the record is your debounce time. If you need the processing to run AFTER the record is deleted by TTL, instead of as soon as the record is created, then you can have DynamoDB trigger a Lambda function on record delete.

As for "what does the polling" that's just how SQS works. It doesn't push messages, you have to poll for them. If you wanted a Lambda function to process the messages then AWS Lambda can poll an SQS queue for you automatically via the Lambda/SQS integration.

I think the real debouncing is effectively running the task after delete and in that case, the newer notifications could update the TTL.
I think this really simulates the debouncing effect that I need.
